# how to get app to run on test device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am currently trying to get my app to run on my iPhone 4. I have the green dot showing in the organizer and the bundle identifier set up right. My test device is linked and plugged in to Xcode and everything in the provisioning profile of the apple developer website is set up correctly. When I run my application to my test device, Xcode delivers a message saying "Build Succeeded", but nothing appears on my test device. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you checked if the selected target device (next to the Stop and Play Button) is showing the name of your device? Did you tried with cmd-r?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of Project, Scheme and Target names. This all must be a same. Try rename to same name

"AppName" and "Appname" is not true. Must be "AppName" and "AppName", or "Appname" and "Appname".

If this will help you, then click Accept button at answer

Answer (score 0):

make sure that have you given provisioning profile names correctly or not in code signing identity in both project and target in your xcode